# How to add data from external API to Umbraco property value model?

Tags: umbraco

I created a custom property editor in Umbraco 12, where I configure a list of products that will be displayed on front page along with their live prices. Property value is saved in DB and looks something like so:

```
{
  type: Array,
  properties: {
    productName: "string",
    productId: "number"
  }
}
```

I get all properties on FE successfully.

Now I would like to enrich this view model to have the following structure, where the price information is filled up form external API on the backend for each request (prices change very frequently):

```
{
  type: Array,
  properties: {
    productName: "string",
    productId: "number",
    price: "number",
    priceTimestamp: "string",
    priceChange: "number"
  }
}
```

Firstly I put the price update into my `PropertyValueConverter`'s `ConvertIntermediateToObject` method, but this updates the price values only update on save action. I need to get updated prices on each request.

I also tried to use `PublishedContentWrapped` but it doesn't get picked up without a controller.
I was lookin into route hijacking and surface controller but I'm not sure how to do this only for one property and not for a page. The thing is that this property could be on more pages and I don't wish to create a new controller for each of them.

I want to get this data with DeliveryAPI.

How should I achieve this?

I'm using Umbraco 12.0.0-RC4